# How to check if data from input exist in QuerySet - Django

Tags: html, django

Can I check if a data from input html is in QuerySet?

exemple:

```
<div>
  <input type="tel" id="phone-number">
  {% if input in client %}
```

Comment: Can you describe little bit broadly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide how you will do this:

1. with a form submit, then you have to create a view(or use the same that is rendering the input but divided by method POST and GET) that process this form and check if the phone_number is in a queryset like `Model.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).exists()`.
2. ajax, for example with jquery, you can do it in any event like on click, on key press, on key up, etc. And then you have to send the phone_number to a view in django, do the same that 1) and return a response to do another thing.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean?

```
{% for i in test %}
 {% if Something in i %}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this?

Comment: No, 
I would like to know how to get data from input html and check if this data is in Object.

or something like that:

<div>
  <input type="tel" id="phone-number">
    {% for tel in clientes %}
    {% if input == tel %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}